# Python None check (redis)

Tags: python, redis-py

I am coding an module using redis-py,
here I have a problem :

```
def get_users_from_usergroup(usergroup):
get_result = r_server.hmget('usergroups', usergroup)
if get_result is not None:
    print('users from the given usegroup [' + usergroup + '] are :')
    print(get_result)
    return (get_result)
else:
   print("Usergroup not found")
   return "error"
```

I make a check on None values but it doesn't work I never enter in the else loop, even though the result is None.
Output :

```
users from the given usegroup [random] are :
[None]
users from the given usegroup [random] are :
[None]
users from the given usegroup [random] are :
['as872 bs940 e0286']
```

I have probably missed something but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> [None] is None
False
```

is the answer to your question. Try to change your condition to:

```
if get_result[0]:
    # there are results
else:
    # there are no results
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work but that:   if get_result != [None]: works. Does it mean that it returns a [None] object instead of a None object ?

Comment: @SteevenBrunner just made a quick fix

Comment: :o I'm beginner in python, here you check if the first value of an arrow is not null then ?

Comment: @SteevenBrunner exactly - you can see this printed in your examples

Comment: Thanks ! I'll validate the answer :)